# How to extract numbers from my dataset and make an array?

Tags: python, extract

i want from the array rank to extract only the numbers

i can't extract only the number i've tried the find all, contains, etc.

```
rank[0]
<td class="blob-num js-line-number" data-line-number="100" id="L100"></td>]
len(rank)
100
>>> import re
>>> [int(s) for s in re.findall(r'\b\d+\b', rank[0])]

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-256-5566677d4eea> in <module>
      1 import re
----> 2 [int(s) for s in re.findall(r'\b\d+\b', rank[0])]

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/re.py in findall(pattern, string, flags)
    221 
    222     Empty matches are included in the result."""
--> 223     return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)
    224 
    225 def finditer(pattern, string, flags=0):

TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Comment: Which numbers do you want? I would suggest using [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) for HTML parsing